# How to compare email and password with the email & password that I saved in my database in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

1. my views.py
2. I want to compare email and password with the email & password that I saved in my database in Django
3. Basically I am creating login signup with the help of models and models data

```
def shoplogin(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        username = request.POST['loginemail']
        password = request.POST['loginpass1']
    
        shopLogin = shop_registration.objects.all()
        username1 = shopLogin.email
        password1 = shopLogin.pass1

        if username == username1 and password == password1:
            messages.success(request, "Success")
            print("login seccess")
            return redirect('createyourshop')

        else:
            messages.error(request, "login failed")
            print("login failed")
            return redirect('createyourshop')

            return HttpResponse('shoplogin')
```

These are my models tables.

My models.py

```
    class shop_registration(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(default='', max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField(default='', max_length=60) #compare this email to 'loginemail'
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=12, default='')
    pass1 = models.CharField(default='', max_length=20) #compare this pass1 to 'loginpass1'
    pass2 = models.CharField(default='', max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you can do:

1. Check all registrations if a email with the input email exists.
2. If the email does not exist, return "login failed".
3. If the email exists, check if the corresponding password matches with the input password.
4. If the passwords also match, then login is successful.

```
def shoplogin(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        input_email = request.POST['loginemail']
        input_password = request.POST['loginpass1']

        try:
            registered_user = shop_registration.objects.get(email=input_email)               
            if input_password == registered_user.password:
                messages.success(request, "Success")
                print("login success")
            else:
                messages.error(request, "wrong password")
                print("wrong password")
        except shop_registration.DoesNotExist:
            messages.error(request, "email does not exist")
            print("email does not exist")
        return redirect('createyourshop')
```

Comment: hey man, thanku so much seriously i am so happy .. God bless you man :-)

Comment: @Oldman Would be good if you can mark this as the accepted answer by clicking on the green tick mark on the answer :)